# Keep two items in the same div without any space or formatting problems

Tags: html, css

So I've run into a little problem with my coding here: I'm trying to keep these two objects on the same line without causing any space errors like in the first Image:

**CSS:**

```
div.title-top {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: ostrich;
    font-size: 46px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 12px;
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="title-top"><img src="http://www.pixelblob.com/img-src/icon/1.png" height="70" width="70">PIXELBLOB STUDIOS</div>
```

**IMAGE #1:**

[image]

(So apparently I can't post images but here's the link)

How would I go about solving this in order to make it more like this:

[image]

(Excuse my bad paint drawing skills, mouses don't make grand replacement to a brush)

(Also sorry if this question has been posted here before, but I don't know what to search for this, banner formatting help? fix extra space problem? they all seem to also come up w/ no answers :c)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it. What's the problem then? there's no space between the image and the text.

Comment: your code looks ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vNzMB/

Comment: @Danield I believe they wanted it centred. Like the first answer has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nAH6V/)

```
img, .title{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.title-top {
    width: 100%;    
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: ostrich;
    font-size: 46px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 12px;
    display: table;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="title-top">
   <img src="http://www.pixelblob.com/img-src/icon/1.png" height="70" width="70" />
   <div class="title">PIXELBLOB STUDIOS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks yours worked, kinda, I hade to use the webkit transform to put it into place but worked for the most part *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You need to `float:left` the image

```
/* Add line height eqaul to image height */
div.title-top {
    line-height:70px;
}

/* Add float to image */
div.title-top img{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: I would see how that would work but it didn't for me, but thanks for answering either way, kinda my first time I didn't get downvoted for not knowing the answer :P

Comment: Also thanks for the margin-right, I know howto code and what to do but I don't have everything on mine, it will atleast make it easier to code the next bits :B